# Chrome Extension to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-chrome-extension

## **Goal**

To write a chrome extension that can send data to a Google Sheet Template I created and allow users to do the same with their version of the template in Google Sheets.

**Webapp approach**

My initial approach which already works is to handle the Chrome Extension to Sheet communication with a deployed webapp as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941814/connecting-chrome-extension-to-google-spreadsheet?rq=4).

This works fine and I've written the majority of my extension using this method without any issues.

The problem with this approach is that I don't want my users to have to deploy a web app to make the app work. My user base will be non-technical, and I don't want each of them to have to go into Apps Script and deploy the web app.

*Note: I went down a rabbit hole seeing if there is a way to auto-deploy a web app with a button push for my users, and such a thing doesn't appear to be possible based on my research.*

**Sheets API approach**

Another approach I saw explained in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227508/write-form-data-from-my-chrome-extension-to-google-sheets) shows how to do this with the Sheets API.

However this approach needs an API key which again would require users to have to create an API key using the developer console. This would be even tougher for them than the first solution.

## **My question**

What is the best general workflow so that chrome extensions can talk to Google Sheets so that it can be easily distributed to users without them having to do anything technical.

Ideally, in my chrome extension, they'd have a place to put the Spreadsheet ID, they'd log into a Chrome browser, and then everything would just work.

## **Research**

I've read dozens of similar articles here on stackoverflow and Googled, but nothing I've found is a simple straightforward approach.

There are extensions out there that seem to do this:

- [Magical](https://www.getmagical.com/integrations/magical-to-google-sheets#:%7E:text=Magical%20is%20a%20chrome%20extension,data%20directly%20to%20Google%20Sheets.) for example is one.